# How do I combine '-size` and '-exec rm' in find?

Tags: find, rm

When I use this, it works:

```
find /home -name "error_log" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But when I try to add a file size limit, it won't remove any files:

```
find /home -size +5000000b -name "error_log" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Any ideas how to get the size limit to work with this?

Comment: Please  add the output of  `find /home -type f -name error_log -ls | sort -nr | head` to your question.  That shows the sizes of the largest error_log files.  Thanks.

Comment: Just two quick questions:
1) Why `rm -rf`. Are it directories which you are recursively deleting?
2) There also is a -delete. No need to exec rm.
And finally: deleting log files may or may not free up any space. If you are writing a script to keep your system clean then make sure that you do not wipe files from the system while they are in use. They will disappear from the directory listing, but still take up disk space if they were in use.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have a server of mine with about 20 wordpress sites on it and the wordpress error_log file gets into the 100m size every couple months. Those are the files I am targeting so the "rm -rf" I just chose because I didn't want to it to hang up on a verbose approval to remove the file. The script removed the files but I'm interested, it won't free the space on the accounts?

Really appreciate the help BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-size` with a suffix of `b` is for 512-byte blocks, not bytes. `5000000b` is 2,560,000,000 bytes or 2.5 GB

Try:

```
find /home -size +5M -name "error_log" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

From the GNU find man page:

> -size n[cwbkMG]
>      File uses n units of space.  The following suffixes can be used:
>
> `b'    for  512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is                   used)
>
> `c'    for bytes
>
> `w'    for two-byte words
>
> `k'    for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
>
> `M'    for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
>
> `G'    for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)
>
> The size does not count  indirect  blocks,  but  it  does  count
>   blocks in sparse files that are not actually allocated.  Bear in
>   mind that the `%k' and`%b' format specifiers of -printf  handle
>   sparse   files  differently.   The  `b'  suffix  always  denotes
>   512-byte blocks and never 1 Kilobyte blocks, which is  different
>   to the behaviour of -ls.

Comment: I tried that +5m but with a lowercase which must of been the error. This one worked perfectly.

Thanks a million.